# How to automatically disable notifications during screen sharing on Windows 10?

Tags: windows-10, notifications, screen-sharing

Is there a setting or an application for Windows 10 that automatically detects that I am sharing my screen and in that case hides or disables my Windows notifications?
The app should also reactivate the notifications immediately after the presentation is finished.

Screen sharing tools are: Google meet and Teams.

**Why?:**

- annoying and takes away focus
- It's unprofessional if something like a "Signal"-message is been showed (I need notifications by this app for specific cases, so turning it off isn't an option).

Answer (score 0):

Use Focus Assist.
From [HowToGeek - How to Use Focus Assist (Do Not Disturb Mode) on Windows 10](https://www.howtogeek.com/349829/how-to-use-focus-assist-do-not-disturb-mode-on-windows-10/)

> Windows 10’s “Focus Assist” feature is a “Do Not Disturb” mode that hides notifications. Windows automatically activates it when you’re playing PC games or mirroring your display—and you can have Windows automatically activate it on a schedule, too.
>
> **How to Enable Focus Assist**
>
> You can manually toggle Focus Assist on and off, if you like.
> Notifications are hidden while it’s enabled.
>
> To do so, right-click the Notification Center icon at the right side
> of your taskbar, point to Focus Assist, and select “Priority Only” if
> you only want to see priority notifications or “Alarms Only” if you
> only want to get alarms.
>
> You can customize which notifications have priority from the Settings
> app. Alarms refers to alarms you set in apps like the included Alarms
> & Clocks app.

Comment: In this article Chris mentioned, that the notifictions will be deactivated when screen is mirrored aka shared. This option doesn't seem to be there if it isn't the "duplicate screen" part is. I will test it.

Comment: I can't test this, but I don't think sharing counts as mirroring. You might get lucky, but you might have to do this manually each time. I can't find any method that can trigger it on a per-app basis other than the generic 'games' setting.

Answer (score -1):

You can use "focus" mode on windows 10 to mute all notifications when you click on it. There is a option to auto mute all when duplicating your sreen(but i've never tried this option), its usefull for me when i want to read something.
Instructions here: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Md9Yesici2g